# E404 'login-history-api-fallback@1.6.0' is not in this registry

Tags: reactjs, npm, registry, npm-install, npm-package

I am trying to run `npm install` for a react js project. It gives the following error.

```
code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/login-history-api-fallback - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'login-history-api-fallback@1.6.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/muhammadtariq/.npm/_logs/2022-06-16T11_48_11_271Z-debug-0.log
```

Here is my package.json code

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@blocto/blocto-connector": "^0.2.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.6.6",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.6",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.1.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
    "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector": "^6.2.13",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "camelcase": "^6.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.2",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.2",
    "file-loader": "6.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
    "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
    "jss": "^10.9.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.11.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.4",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "5.0.2",
    "prompts": "2.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "resolve": "1.18.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "semver": "7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-pnp": "1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "web3": "^1.7.3",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4"
  },
```

There is no package name login-history-api-fallback in package.json
I also tried to install single package like axios. Still same error.
I tried to set npm config registry but same issue.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: "npm ls login-history-api-fallback" will show you which packages depend on login-history-api-fallback

Comment: "npm ls login-history-api-fallback" gives "└── (empty)". There is no package name with login-history-api-fallback on npm.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and failure. I tried this:

- Copy package.json to other location
- Created new package.json with `npm init`
- Copy dependencies to new package.json
- Run `npm install`

And it worked!!!